# Javascript array element undefined, it really isn't

Tags: javascript, google-maps

can someone explain this to me. The image below depicts the output in the Chrome console. When I log out the main object, the console shows all the properties. As you can see the array has a property named "markers", its not undefined, because I can browse through it. But when I try to log out this property, lets say object.markers, it says that the property is undefined. Now I am really confused, because as you can see I log them sequentially.

First object is directionsRenderer. The second object is 'j' property of directionsRenderer. Third is 'markers' property of directionsRenderer 'j' property.

[image]

Here is the source
[image]

Comment: Its funny, because .j.markers is exactly the same as .j.j

Comment: directionsRenderer.j.markers is undefined.  directionsRenderer.j and directionsRenderer.markers are what your picture shows.

Comment: directionsRenderer.markers is undefined.

Comment: I'd upvote the question again if I could: It's **so nice** to see someone post a question and stick around to answer questions, do further experiments, etc., etc. The question as it stands deserves more votes than it's gotten; the effort and attention only reinforces that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet what we're seeing here is the surprising way that the console works in Chrome.

In Chrome, when you "log" an object, you don't just get the object *as it was when it was logged*. You get a live interaction with that object. The first time you expand that object, you see a list of its properties *as of when you expand it*, not as they were when it was logged.

I suspect if you do

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(directionsRenderer));
```

...you'll see that `.j.markers` is indeed undefined, because it's been filled in later, asynchronously, after the code you've shown has run.

You can see this effect if you do this: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/hucivu/1)

```
var a = {b: {}};
console.log(a); // Note that b is currently empty
setTimeout(function() {
    a.b.c = "foo";
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = "Now expand <code>a.b</code> in the console";
    document.body.appendChild(p);
});
```

Note that we log `a` when `a.b` is empty, then **after** we log it, we add a property to `b`. When you expand `a` in the console, you see `b` **with the `c` property**.

E.g., what you have is a timing problem. There's some asynchronous call involved, and you need to find the callback associated with it before you can access `directionsRenderer.j.markers`.

Comment: I cannot stringify it, because its a circular structure. But your explanation seems logical.

Comment: @UrosHercog: A pleasure to help someone who takes the time to help themselves.